# What's on the plaque of the Valyrian Steel Catspaw dagger?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire, object-identification

The [Valyrian Steel Catspaw blade](http://www.valyriansteel.com/shop/swords/catspaw-blade/prod_20.html) comes with the following plaque:

[image: Catspaw blade]

As far as I can tell the animals just seem to be random ones that represent the different Houses.

For example,

- Lion: Lannister;
- Stag: Baratheon;
- Wolf: Stark.

There are some smaller ones I can’t make out. What are they? Do they represent any House?

The scene also appears to be quite random. Is there any significance to it? Is it linked to the blade in any way?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The top image depicts aftermath of Robert's Rebellion. The stag stands victorious and all the animals are bowing to him.:

[image]

From left to right(With exception of Stag of Baratheon in the center):

1. House Mormont (A Bear)

   [image]
2. House Crakehall (A Boar)

   [image]
3. House Lannister (A Lion)

   [image]
4. House Florent (A fox, shoutout to KRyan for pointing out the Fox)

   [image]
5. House Blackmont/Mallister (Depending on whether the bird's a vulture or an Eagle)

   [image]
   [image]
6. House Swann (Two Swans)

   [image]
7. House Arryn (A Falcon, thanks to Skooba)

   [image]
8. House Stark (A Wolf)

   [image]
9. House Bracken (A Stallion)

   [image]
10. House Swyft (A Rooster)

    [image]

The bottom sequence shows Robert's Rebellion where a Stag, a Lion and a Wolf are fighting a three headed-Dragon. That signifies the fight of Lannisters, Starks and Baratheons against the Targaryens.

[image]

It seems to be random and unrelated to the blade. I suppose that's an attempt by the vendor to mimic the opening sequence of Game of Thrones TV Show.

Comment: Actually looking at the bottom scene a bit more the Lion is "behind" the dragon and going for the neck. So looks to signify the backstabbing done by them.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Nah they all are fighting one head each. To me it seems Baratheons are backstabbing